# Reading exif data with .net framework (System.Drawing.Imaging)

Tags: c#, .net, exif

I am using the .net framework to read the exif metadata from a jpg file. The problem is how to convert the PropertyItem.Value (that is byte array) in a readable form such as a string.

For example with this code I read the GPSAltitude value of a picture:

```
        var pic = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\mypic.jpg");
        var GPSAltitude = pic.GetPropertyItem(6);
```

and the GPSAltitude.Value is a byte array like this: {75,2,0,0,1,0,0,0}.

I know that the altitude is 587 m.s.l... but how do I go from that byte array to 587 ?

I tried to read it with ASCIIencoding and some other encodings but I get something like "K\0\0\0\0\0".

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) will work.

```
public static void Main()
   {

      byte[] bytes = {75, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
      int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
      Console.WriteLine("Returned value: {0}", result);
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
```

Result is : 587

Comment: by the way: is there a method for the opposite operation: from the int 587 to the array of byte {75, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} ?

Comment: @user1472131 BitConverter.GetBytes() doesnt return original byte array somehow... interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the answers already given, you might want to check out the actual [Exif spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207065832/http://exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF).

**GPSAltitude** (page 47)

Indicates the altitude based on the reference in GPSAltitudeRef. Altitude is expressed as one RATIONAL value. The reference unit is meters.

**GPSAltitudeRef** (page 47)

Indicates the altitude used as the reference altitude. If the reference is sea level and the altitude is above sea level, 0 is given. If the altitude is below sea level, a value of 1 is given and the altitude is indicated as an absolute value in the GPSAltitude tag. The reference unit is meters. Note that this tag is BYTE type, unlike other reference tags.

**RATIONAL** (Page 14)

Two LONGs. The first LONG is the numerator and the second LONG expresses the denominator.

**LONG** (Page 14)

A 32-bit (4-byte) unsigned integer.

So, `{75, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}` is `{75, 2, 0, 0} / {1, 0, 0, 0}`. When you read the bytes as bits as little endian you get `0000 0010 0100 1011 / 0000 0000 0000 0001` which calculates to 587. The other answers explain *how* to get the answer but hopefully this explains why it is that way.

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert your `byte[]` to an `int` to see the 587 value you expect:

```
var pic = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\mypic.jpg");         
var GPSAltitude = pic.GetPropertyItem(6); 
var altitude = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(GPSAltitude,0);
```